# Computer only starts recovery mode Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, recovery-mode

Computer only starts recovery mode

I bought an ASUS F553M, apparently the manufacturer's reference is X553MA. Installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and with the exception of giving the error "* will now halt" instead of turning off everything was working well.

I tried to manually command

ctrl + alt + t

sudo shutdown -h

and

sudo poweroff

but the problem remained. Since it didn't affect computer operation I proceeded to shut down the computer manually. However after same time the computer started to block at start-up and, currently only starts in Linux 3.13.0-40 generic (recovery mode). Also I checked the BIOS and is the version installed, 209, is the latest available.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Thanks,
Vasco Reis

Answer (score 0):

I have an Asus F553M.  It hung on boot and it hung on shut down.  Only recovery mode gave access.
The live DVD worked fine.
The fault was initially diagnosed to be caused by a Logitech unifying nano transmitter for the cordless mouse plugged into the USB2 port.
Once unplugged everything worked as it should.  Subsequently other nano transmitters were tried but the system functioned normally.

Thereafter, when the Logitech unifying transmitter was re-inserted the system continued to function normally.

In addition, since the laptop came with an unwanted Windows 8.1 pre-installed, I deleted all the partitions using gparted from the Linux install DVD, created a new ext4 partition and installed the Linux system.
Re-partitioning removed the GPT boot and re-instituted the MBR.  If GPT is preferred, you can redo this via "sudo gdisk /dev/sda" and make a selection from the choices offered.  To use "gdisk" the gdisk facility has to be installed from synaptic.  Please ensure that your MBR is backed up.  See http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/wipegpt.html

"Secure Boot" had been disabled.